# Overriding CSS property all: unset

Tags: css, css-cascade

For a CSS framework I am developing, I am using `all: unset`, which by itself works fine:

```css
#foo { all: unset; }
```

However, in certain cases, I want to "undo" the effect of this rule, as in

```css
#foo:hover { all: auto; }
```

However, this obviously does not work because there is no value of `auto` for `all`. Instead, we have the values `inherit` and `initial`, which instead of "cancelling" the `all` property, have different effects: of reverting all values to their parent's value, or their initial (I assume this means system-level default values).

To accomplish what I want, I am currently doing

```css
#foo:not(:hover) { all: unset; }
```

which works fine, but is not too scalable if I want to do this for multiple pseudo-classes, for example, and I would prefer to override the `all: unset` property? Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not appear to be possible to undo the effects of the `all` property once it has been specified. This may be due to `all` being a shorthand property (that happens to accept only the CSS-wide keywords as values).

You can't erase a shorthand declaration from the cascade the same way that css-cascade-4's introduction of the `revert` keyword allows you to erase author-level declarations, and that's because a shorthand property doesn't exist as its own entity in the cascade; instead, it simply represents all of its component properties. Like with the more traditional shorthand properties such as `background` and `font`, the only way to override a shorthand declaration that has been applied is to re-specify the values for the longhands that were overridden, either via longhand declarations or via another shorthand declaration. But you can't do the latter with the `all` property since it only accepts CSS-wide keywords.

As the former is obviously not practical with the `all` shorthand, since you can't predict which author-level declarations are being overridden to begin with, your only other option is to restrict it via a selector, thereby preventing it from ever applying in specific circumstances in the first place. Hopefully we will see more implementations of level 4 `:not()` in the near future, which will make writing selectors a little easier.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to what BoltClock explained, what you want is not currently possible even for non-shorthand properties.

```css
* { color: red; }
#foo { color: unset; }
#foo:hover { color: /* How to revert to red? */ }
```

Once you add a value which wins the cascade, there is not way to tell the cascade to "go back" and get the previous winner instead. You must set it explicitly, but that's only possible if you know it.

The closest thing is the [`revert` keyword](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#default), introduced by CSS Cascade 4, which rolls back the cascade to previous origin level. But rolling the cascade back to the previous winner in the same origin level is currently not possible.

Then, the solution is restricting your selectors to apply only when you want them. This way there is no need to undo.

Comment: "But rolling the cascade back to the previous winner in the same origin level is currently not possible." And the reason for this is because the cascade can't tell what the "previous winner" is in the first place. If it just assumed the order of declarations, specificity notwithstanding, that would be very error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
all: revert
```

More infos here [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all)

Comment: That reverts values to their browser defaults, which is one of the things the OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: Yes I know, but I don't know how they're handling the styles so they might have origins that permit the use of revert.

Comment: Yes, I saw `revert`, but besides not doing what I want, it is pretty much unsupported.

Comment: I've had a similar question and this helped with my issue [How to prevent very generic CSS selector to interact with library CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72998953/387194). and in 2022 the [support is pretty good](https://caniuse.com/css-revert-value).