# How to prevent very generic CSS selector to interact with library CSS?

Tags: html, css

In jQuery Terminal library some time ago I've got a bug report that the library doesn't work properly. It happen few times and usually, the user used something like this:

```css
* {
   font-family: arial;
}
```

Which broke the library. I've fixed that by adding font and font-family to all elements inside `.terminal`. But this is just a hack, what if the user used:

```css
* {
   border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

or

```css
div {
   border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

I've seen people recommend something like:

```css
* {
   all: unset;
}
```

and I've also seen something like this:

```css
* { all: initial !important; }
```

referred as ultimate CSS reset. But when I use something like this:

```css
.terminal * { all: initial !important; }
```

my library breaks completely. Because my CSS is not applied anymore, everything has a default state, that can't be changed. I've also tried without `!important`.

So my question what is the use of all property if it can't reset the value because you can't change it? An additional related question is there a way to reset everything inside .terminal so users can't set it with a generic selector like `*` or `div`? Is there a better way than setting every possible CSS property on `.terminal *` selector? What if new CSS property is added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `revert` keyword does what I want:

```css
.terminal, .terminal * { all: revert; }
```

This seems to work. See [browser support for revert keyword](https://caniuse.com/css-revert-value).

```css
div {
   border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
   font-family: sans-serif;
}
.terminal, .terminal * { all: revert; }

.terminal {
  background: black;
  color: #ccc;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div>Applied</div>
<br/>
<div class="terminal">
  <div>not affected</div>
  <br/>
</div>
```